# Validation not firing dynamic

Tags: c#, asp.net

My validators are not firing when handled from the usercontrol code behind. My usercontrol consists of the following:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSource" cssClass="value"
    ValidationGroup="formbuilder" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFV" runat="server"  
    ControlToValidate="txtSource" Enabled="true" ErrorMessage="*required"    
    ValidationGroup="formbuilder"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="REV" runat="server"
    ValidationGroup="formbuilder" ControlToValidate="txtSource" Enabled="false">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

As you can see, I have to put in errormessage and enabled to get it to fire. My code behind for the user control is as follows. I am setting the two required variables as such.

```
public bool EnabledRequiredField
{
    set { RFV.Enabled = value; }
}        

public bool EnabledRegularExpression
{
    set { REV.Enabled = value; }
}

private string _ErrorMsgForRequiredField;

public string ErrorMsgForRequiredField
{
    get { return _ErrorMsgForRequiredField; }
    set { RFV.ErrorMessage = value; }
}
```

But unless I hard code Enabled="true" and ErrorMessage="*required", it will not fire. When I place that in hard code it does. Any ideas? I am loading the control via the following method.

```
 if (control.Required == "true")
 {
     textBoxControl.EnabledRequiredField = true;  
     textBoxControl.RequiredFieldText = "*required";
     textBoxControl.ErrorMsgForRequiredField = "*required";
     textBoxControl.RequiredFieldDisplay = ValidatorDisplay.Static;
     textBoxControl.ValidationGroup = "formbuilder";
 }

 pnlControls.Controls.Add(textBoxControl);
```

Comment: Does your `<asp:Button>` (or whatever is initiating the post-back) have the `formbuilder` group set?

Comment: What is `control.Required`?  Are you sure it's a string?  Should it be `control.Require == true`?

Comment: @freefaller the code where the if control.required =true is comming from a parsed xml file i converted it to string the values it hits the brake point and sets all the properties bar message and enabled.

Comment: `REV` is set to `Enabled="false"` in the markup, but you're not calling `EnabledRegularExpression = true` in the code-behind, so that will never be enabled.  I don't know why `RFV` is not firing, other than if the post-back initiation isn't set to `formbuilder` group

Comment: @fre rev is only used if it is regular expression the code switches between them obv depinging on the type